# How to preserve object reference through the configuration change?

Tags: android, dialog

I've created reusable text query dialog fragment. But it do not handle config. changes. After fragment recreation mClickListener is null (as expected). The question is - How can I preserve the callback?
(I'm new to java and can be unaware of common java patterns/solutions)

```
public class TextQueryDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
private OnDialogListener mClickListener;
private EditText mTextWidget;

public void setClickListener(OnDialogListener listener) {
    mClickListener = listener;
}

public String getQueryText() {
    return mTextWidget.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View queryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.query_dialog_text, null);
    mTextWidget = (EditText) queryView.findViewById(R.id.query_dialog_text);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setView(queryView)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            if(null != mClickListener)
                mClickListener.OnPositiveClick();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, 
                                           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            if(null != mClickListener)
                mClickListener.OnNegativeClick();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Usage:

```
TextQueryDialogFragment dialog = new TextQueryDialogFragment();
dialog.setQueryText(mBookmarkTitle);
dialog.setClickListener(new OnDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnPositiveClick() {
            String title = dialog.getQueryText();
            //do work here
        }

        @Override
        public void OnNegativeClick() {}
    });
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MYTAG");
```

Serializable will not work and hence onSaveInstanceState is not what I need. Parcelable might do (with aidl and IBinder) but it's too much for such a simple task.

So far I found two more or less suitable solutions:

- Store callbacks in Application and retrieve them by id/tag [taken from here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html)
- update callbacks in the on create of parent fragment:

  TextQueryDialogFragment dialog = (TextQueryDialogFragment) 
               getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(RENAME_TAG);
  if(null != dialog) {
  dialog.setClickListener(getListener());
  }

Is there any better solutions or those two are ok?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple and has nothing to do with `onRetainConfigurationInstance` or other techniques mentioned here. Just search for the `TextQueryDialogFragment` instance in the `FragmentManager` when re-creating your parent fragment and set your listener again if the instance is still there.

Add following code to the parent's `onCreateView` method:

```
TextQueryDialogFragment retFragment = 
(TextQueryDialogFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MYTAG");

if(retFragment != null)
{
    retFragment.setClickListener(new OnDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnPositiveClick() {
            String title = dialog.getQueryText();
            //do work here
        }

        @Override
        public void OnNegativeClick() {}
    }
);
}
```

In this case I would rather implement onClickListener by your fragment class so that you could rewrite it this way:

```
TextQueryDialogFragment retFragment = 
(TextQueryDialogFragment )getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MYTAG");

if(retFragment != null)
{
    retFragment.setClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `onRetainConfigurationInstance`, you can return any object that you want.

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() { ... }
```

Then you can get it in `onCreate()`:

```
if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
  instance = (Type) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

However, I'm not sure why you would need to retain an `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Well, if i won't retain OnClickListener, I'll have to restore it some how because it become null. You said I shouldn't retain callback. As I noted above I'm new to Java and my approach can be incorrect. Could you please point me what implementation would be correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem and the answer from vitakot was the solution! But my case was just a little more complex: I have a Fragment 'MyAttributeFragment' that use a DialogFragment for text input. This MyAttributeFragment is used more than one time in the same Activity, so a static tag like "MYTAG" for the DialogFragment is not unique. I solved this by taking the ID of MyAttributeFragment to identifiy the owning Fragment.

```
//Create DialogFragment with the unique ID of the owning fragment 
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), String.valueOf(this.getId()));
```